# How to obtain parameters for conditional gaussian for more than two variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, covariance

We can obtain $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ for a conditional gaussian with two variables, $a$ and $b$, $p(x_{a}|x_{b})$ like this:

$$\mu_{a|b}= \mu_{a}+\Sigma_{ab}\Sigma^{-1}_{bb}(x_{b}-\mu_{b})$$
$$\Sigma_{a|b} = \Sigma_{aa}-\Sigma_{ab}\Sigma^{-1}_{bb}\Sigma_{ba}$$

Question: How do I extend obtaining $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ for 3, 4, ..., $n$ conditioning variables?

Reference: Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006

Comment: Here $x_a$ and $x_b$ are vectors in general, so what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: @StubbornAtom. How to compute $$\mu_{a|b,c}$$ and similarly for $$\Sigma_{a|b,c}$$? I want to know how to extend obtaining $$a$$ when conditioning on more than just $$b$$.

Comment: Take $b'=(b,c)$ and use the same result for $\mu_{a\mid b'}$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Do you want to provide a full answer?